# Como criar uma consulta com tabela inexistente e sem erro

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Tenho uma consulta que é executada em vários schemas diferentes no banco de dados, e existe uma tabela especifica que so algums schemas tem, e se existe o valor retorna.

```
SELECT t.coluna1
      ,t.coluna2
      ,(SELECT coluna3
         FROM tabelaquepodenaoexistir
        WHERE coluna4 = 'S'
          AND coluna5 = 'N') as coluna 3
  FROM tabelaqueexisteemtodosschemas t
```

Em alguns schemas essa consulta retorna o que deve retornar, mas em alguns retorna o erro:

> ORA-00942: a tabela ou view não existe

Observações:

- Não pode usar acesso de DBA ou SYS.
- Não posso criar essa tabela.
- Não posso criar uma function no schema.

Comment: Não tenho, tenho a `user_tables`

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:11670337038966     No mesmo owner se tem o user_tables sim , não ocorre o motivo para não ter , um solução poderia ser rodar o sql via "execute immediate" tratando a exceção um exemplo no link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente algo como :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_record
  (user_name    IN  VARCHAR2,
   service_type IN  VARCHAR2,
   record       OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
  query VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN  
    BEGIN
      -- Following SELECT statement is vulnerable to modification
      -- because it uses concatenation to build WHERE clause.
      query := 'SELECT value FROM secret_records WHERE user_name='''
               || user_name 
               || ''' AND service_type=''' 
               || service_type 
               || '''';
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Query: ' || query);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query INTO record;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record: ' || record);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;--IGNORA O ERRO 
    END;
END;    
/
```

Tratando o erro , acho que até existe um "handle" para o erro expecífico de tabela não existe.

Fonte : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01101